# How to get and add the values of two elements by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        var sub_total = $("sub_total").text();
                        alert(sub_total);
        var ship_total = $("ship_total").val()
                        alert(ship_total);

        var new_total = sub_total + ship_total;

        $('#new_total').html( new_total.toFixed(2));
    });

</script>
```

I'm using alert to test the output and It is not getting the value inside the span ID.

```
$<span id="sub_total"><?php echo $sub_total = number_format($this->cart->total(), 2); ?></span></td>
```

This does display correctly on the page but the alert is a blank box. Causing the `new_total` value to stat `NaN` not a number.

How do I add the values in these two fields?

Comment: its good practice to provide the radix when using parseInt in javascript.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You forgot to get the value - you are only getting the element

Since you're already using jQuery you can get the value like

```
var sub_total = parseInt($("#sub_total").text());// this is where you need to use .text()
var ship_total = parseInt($("#ship_total").text());
```

or if you want to keep plain js..

```
document.getElementById("sub_total").value
```

Since you have $ in your text you need to get rid of it before parsing it.  You can use regex as @Bubbles stated or whatever method you want to remove the `$` sign.. ex. substring.. split..

```
$.trim($("#sub_total").text().split('$')[1])
```

or

```
$.trim($("#sub_total").text()).substring(1)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a complete novice to `JS` I'm trying to work in your suggestion but I find the syntax confusing. Can you see my revised question code. Thank you

Comment: I don't have a `$` in there. It is outside of the `span`

Comment: @fabio but your html shows that there is `$` in there.. I'm confused

Comment: Hey yeah in the example -- sorry my mistake. I am revising my code. Please look again in sec

Comment: hi i cleaned this up so that it makes sense. can you please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Thanks -- i was getting a result of `5020` instead of `70` I forgot to add parseInt -- thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

wirey gives a good review of part of the problem, but as is I don't believe it's enough. "parseInt" won't work on "$20", you have to remove the dollar sign first. If you're feeling lazy, this is nothing a good regex won't be able to solve in short order:

```
var sub_total = parseInt($("#sub_total").text().match(/[0-9]+/)));
var ship_total = parseInt($("#ship_total").text().match(/[0-9]+/)));
```

This will just grab the number from the span, then parse it.

Comment: The `$` is in the `HTML` not in the actual `PHP` returned value. Is that what you mean?

Comment: There's no PHP in what you posted, but the "sub_total" and "ship_total" spans contain dollar value characters. They cannot be parsed as integers, so you have to remove the dollar value before you try to parse them as an integer.

Comment: Hey sorry about that - I omitted the `PHP` here .. I revised my code. Please see the new revision for clarification.